# Coloring rows and columns in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, color

I'm trying to put together a series of tables that show row reduction with simplex method (operations research concept). I'm trying to highlight the rows and columns used in simplex method, and these specific rows and columns change all the time. I've attempted the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape,paperwidth=3in,paperheight=3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\columncolor{gray!75}}M}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{}
\begin{tabular}{|MPM|}
\hline
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & z_2 \\
x_3 & y_3 & z_3 \\
x_4 & y_4 & z_4 \\
x_5 & y_5 & z_5 \\
x_6 & y_6 & z_6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

but it seems that each call to `\rowcolor` overrides the column color specified. Is there anyway to work around this behavior?

Comment: There is some precedence set in terms of colour application. Using `\cellcolor{gray!75}` inside the affected cells (`y_3` and `y_5`) overwrites what `\rowcolors` insert.

Comment: Unfortunately, this particular TeX is being generated by a rather intensive script. At that point, it'd be easier to simply have *every* 'affected' cell be colored this way.

Comment: So it seems like you're after reversing the precedence here. That is, column colour should be written *after* the row colour (always)?

Comment: That would actually work, I think. Post it as an answer and it'll have a good chance of being marked :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

colortbl fairly arbitrarily gives row color precedence over column color, if you wish to reverse that decision you just need to change the order of `\CT@column@color` and `\CT@row@color` You can do this by applying a patch macro as below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape,paperwidth=3in,paperheight=3in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\tmpp#1\@addtopreamble#2#3!{%
    \tmp#2!{#1}{#3}}



\def\tmp#1\CT@column@color\CT@row@color#2!#3#4{%
\def\@classz{#3\@addtopreamble{#1\CT@row@color\CT@column@color#2}#4}}

\expandafter\tmpp\@classz!
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\columncolor{gray!75}}M}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{}
\begin{tabular}{|MPM|}
\hline
x_1 & y_1 & z_1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & z_2 \\
x_3 & y_3 & z_3 \\
x_4 & y_4 & z_4 \\
x_5 & y_5 & z_5 \\
x_6 & y_6 & z_6 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the environments of `nicematrix`, you can specify in which order you want to apply the color instructions.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{NiceArray}{|ccc|}
\CodeBefore
  \columncolor{gray!75}{2}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{}
\Body
  \Hline
  x_1 & y_1 & z_1 \\
  x_2 & y_2 & z_2 \\
  x_3 & y_3 & z_3 \\
  x_4 & y_4 & z_4 \\
  x_5 & y_5 & z_5 \\
  x_6 & y_6 & z_6 \\
  \Hline
\end{NiceArray}\]


\[\begin{NiceArray}{|ccc|}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{}
  \columncolor{gray!75}{2}
\Body
  \Hline
  x_1 & y_1 & z_1 \\
  x_2 & y_2 & z_2 \\
  x_3 & y_3 & z_3 \\
  x_4 & y_4 & z_4 \\
  x_5 & y_5 & z_5 \\
  x_6 & y_6 & z_6 \\
  \Hline
\end{NiceArray}\]

\end{document}
```

Moreover, you will have a perfect output in all the PDF viewers.

[image: Output of the above code]